# jQuery class adding and removing with click and mouseleave

Tags: jquery

I just want to control a div by toggling a class on click, as well as removing it when the mouse leaves the div.

I had it working with mouseout, but when I entered over a child element, the mouseOut triggered, so I know I need to use mouseleave. I am just unsure how incorporate telling jQuery the mouse has entered.

UPDATE:
It seems functions won't work when I use mouseenter and mouseleave BUT
they do work when I swap them to mouseover and mouseout.

Here is the site: http://danixd.com/test/

It has a lot on, but here is the code. I referred back to the old jquery I was using.

jQuery

```
$(function(){
            $('.main').click(function() { 
                $(this).toggleClass('activated');
            });
        });



$(function(){
            $('.main').mouseleave(function() { 
                $(this).removeClass('activated');
            });
        });
```

Comment: You want mouseenter to add the class?

Comment: No, I just want mouse click to add the class.

Comment: mouseclick is toggling the class. If you want it to add the class, then use .addClass

Comment: I want mouse click to toggle:

To activate class:
Click div

To de-activate class:
Click div / mouse out of div

Comment: can you post your HTML!?

Comment: It is a big old chunk of html, I have left this bit till last really. I'll upload the entirety of it.

It seems to be that mouseenter and mouseleave are not doing a thing, where as, when I switch the code from mouseleave to mouseout, it works.

Comment: Does `.main` cover a large part of the page? With `mouseleave`, it doesn't fire unless you actually leave that element. I believe `mouseout` fires if you leave any sub-elements of `.main`. So if `.main` covers your entire page, that may be the issue.

Comment: No, the main class is on several small articles that scale when the class is activated using webkit.

There is a hidden div inside the .main class which only appears when the class is activated. I would have been able to use mouseout if that was not the case.

The code is real messy and needs tidying up, but I can't understand the mouseleave not working. Could it be because there are many .main classes on the page rather than just one?

Comment: and this is why it won't work!

Comment: The quantity of `.main` classes shouldn't matter. Unless there's some issue with them overlapping (not sure if that would be an issue), then it seems like it should work. I'll look closer at your code.

Comment: Well, after pasting your code, when I click on one of the `.main` sections (which appears to be smaller sub-sections in the vertical black areas) what happens is a click causes a semi-transparent box to appear. Then if I either click or move the mouse away, it disappears. (Please note that I'm using the jQuery from my solution below.) Does this sound like the behavior you expected?

Comment: Yes.
The columns are <sections>
Inside the columns are <articles> which have the class of main.

When you click on one of these articles, I want the article to double in size and do what you say.

I am using the jquery you added below and the click works, but when the mouse leaves the box, nothing happens. Could it be something as stupid as I need a newer version of jquery?

Comment: Unbelievable! I just updated jQuery and your solution is working an absolute treat! Thank you so much.

Comment: I should have thought to ask what jQuery version you had. Anyway, glad it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand, you want to add the class on 'click', and remove the class on 'click' OR 'mouseleave'.

If so, you could do something like this.

```
$('.main').click(function() { 
    var $ths = $(this);
    if($ths.hasClass('activated'))
        $ths.removeClass('activated');
    else
        $ths.addClass('activated');
}).mouseleave(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('activated');
});
```

Comment: this is nice! ;-) `}).mouseleave` well done! i have never know that we can use it with click and mouselieave together! ;-)  +1

Comment: They are really not together. They are two separate events assigned to `.main` that represent actions of the client. Is the same as doing `$('.main').click(func...` and `$('.main').mouseleave(func...`

Comment: you mean they are not like es: classic .mouseenter }).mouseleave ?

Comment: @aSeptik - I'm not exactly sure what your comment means. They are simply chained in jQuery fashion. They could easily be assigned separately as I indicated in my comment above. But there is nothing inherently 'together' about them. They are two separate events, just like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are two separate events. You can assign handlers to one, or both, or neither.

Answer (score 1):

> I am just unsure how incorporate
>   telling jQuery the mouse has entered.

If that is the case, then there is no need to handle the click event, from what I understand:

```
$('.main').mouseenter(function() { 
    $(this).addClass('activated');
}).mouseleave(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('activated');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
    $('.main').click(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("class").indexOf("activate") > -1) {
                $(this).removeClass("activate");
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("activate");
            }
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("activate");
    });
```